# Python/Tkinter: bind to event related to currently selected menu item

Tags: python, menu, tkinter

Wondering if there's a menu event I can bind to that's related to the currently selected menu item? By menu item I mean the items that show up in a popup menu like New, Open, Save, etc.

Use case: I would like to update a statusbar area of our application with a description of the currently selected menu item.

Any ideas appreciated.

Thank you,
Malcolm

Comment: Relevant solution: [add-a-tooltip-to-menu-item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55316791/how-can-i-add-a-tooltip-to-menu-item-in-tkinter-python-2-7/55343447#55343447)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind to the `<<MenuSelect>>` event.

Comment: Thank you. The <<MenuSelect>> event is exactly what I'm looking for. Unfortunately, I'm having a challenge trying to manage this event once I've captured it. Specifically, I bind to a function defined as update_statusbar( event=None ). A simple print statement within this function confirms that my event binding is correct. However, event.widget returns a string vs. a widget reference. It looks like I'm not getting a normal event object. Does this sound right? Any suggestions on how I can determine the currently selected menu item via the event object I receive?

Answer (score -1):

There's an `<Enter>` event that is triggered when the mouse pointer enters a widget's space. Depending on how you're building your menu, you may be able to use it.

See http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/events-and-bindings.htm for more

Comment: The Tkinter menu building commands don't return a widget reference for me to bind to, eg. the menu method add_command() returns None.

Comment: @Malcolm I feared that, since you're structuring your menu in the "traditional way" I don't think there's an event to support what you want.

Comment: The link is broken.